# create a Set template class using the Standard C++ Library vector as an underlying implementation

Tags: c++, templates, generics, iterator, set

I just read a chapter on templates and iterators but this still is hard to understand. basically i want to create a Set template class that accepts only one of each type of object that you put into it, implemented using a vector.

Problem is, I don't know how to write the insert function in the Set class, and the constructor in the nested iterator class. Also, most of the functions I have provided are examples from the chapter in the text, I do not even know if they are necessary or I am doing it right. Comments? Because this is a very confusing one. Here is my code:

```
//testSetClass.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/****************************CLASS DEFINITION*********************************/

// -----------------------------------------
 //         SET
 // -----------------------------------------
template <class T>
class Set
{
    vector<T> theSet;
public:
    Set() {}
    Set(const Set& s): theSet(s.theSet){} //copy constructor
    ~Set(){ theSet.clear(); }

    void insert(T t) 
    {
        //insert in orderly fashion? as set class does too
        //also, how do i check for duplicates?
        theSet.push_back(t);
    }

    //nested iterator class: that supports the begin() and end() sentinel
    class iterator; //declaration
    friend class iterator;
    class iterator //definition
    {
        Set<T>& s;
        int index;
    public:
        iterator(const Set<T>& ss): s(ss), index(0){}
        //to create the "end sentinel" operator:
        iterator(Set<T>& ss,bool):s(ss){} //???

        T operator*() {return s.theSet.at(index);} //is this right?

        T operator++() //prefix form
        {
            return ++s.theSet.at(index);
        }
        T operator++(int) //postfix form
        {
            return s.theSet.at(index)++;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& ri)const {return index!=ri.index;}
    };

    //iterators begin() and end()
    iterator begin()const { return iterator (*this); }
    //create the end sentinel:
    iterator end() { return iterator (*this,true); } //why?
};


/*************************************END OF CLASS DEFINITIONS*********************************/


/* *****************************************************************************
 *  MAIN 
 * *****************************************************************************
 *  
 *  REMARKS:
 *     to test that the class works correctly.
 * *****************************************************************************/

int main (int argv, char const *argc[])
{
    Set<int> other;


    for(int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
        other.insert(i);

    for(Set<int>::iterator start = other.begin(); start != other.end(); start++)
        cout<<*start<<endl;

    cout << "\n\nProgram ends successfully!" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement std::set specifications using a std::vector as an educational exercise?

Comment: once you are done with it you can get good feedback from the folks at code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //also, how do i check for duplicates?

With `theSet.find()`....

> iterator(Set& ss,bool):s(ss){} //???

That's not going to work.  Many options, easiest being to also set `index` to `s.theSet.size()` so the existing `!=` will work.

> T operator*() {return s.theSet.at(index);} //is this right?

Nope... you need to return a `T&` to - rather than a ***copy*** of - the `vector`'s element.

> operator++ / operator++(int)

You need to increment the iterator (i.e. `index`), not increment what the iterator addresses, and should return `*this` (with return type `iterator&`).  Study some iterator implementations....

> iterator end() { return iterator (*this,true); } //why?

Why what?  Anyway, you'd ideally provide `const` versions of `begin()` and `end()` that return `const_iterator`s (which would be pretty much like `iterator` but only expose `const T&`), as well as non-`const` versions returning `iterator`s: you're mixing these two ideas, with `iterator begin() const`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::vector<T>::iterator` for your iterator.  And similar for your `const_iterator`.

To find, use `std::equal_range`.  If `first==second`, return `end()`.

To insert, find.  If it is already there, stop.  If it isn't there, insert it.  The lazy way to insert it is to push back, then sort.  Do it the lazy way first.

Once you have done the above, you have a working `Set<T>`.  Test it against `std::set<T>` with a bunch of data.  Write a bunch of unit tests to make sure this `Set<T>` works just like `std::set<T>` with regards to duplicates, ordering, finding, etc.

---

Now make your `Set<T>` more efficient.  Replace that `Find` with a call to `lower_bound` and `<`, and insert the element where it is supposed to be instead of insert-then-sort.  (It is ok that this makes no sense to you; get a working `Set` before even reading this, then spend some time unpacking it).

Or, make a lazy-sort `Set<T>` that appends blindly, and only sorts exponentially rarely on insert.  On read, it either sorts, or it examines the sorted part with a binary search and the remaining (small) part with a linear search.  Or somesuch.

Another improvement would be to write a manual `iterator` like above; one that isn't invalidated as easily as a `std::vector` iterator.  This is ... tricky to get right.

But work on efficiency after you have correctness.